# how Do i echo userName and user2name from two diffrent tables in while loop

Tags: php

[image: Look at this fb screenshot 1st upper part has userName and the 2nd half part has pageName so i want same query]   I have Two Tables `user`which has field `userName` and another table `page` which has field `pageUserName` so im selecting this two tables form the database in while loop but i want to echo this two Names in same while loop one after another like we have in FB their are userName as Well as Page names in news feed how can i do this ????

```
    <?php  
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN page ON user.userID=page.userID") ;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc());
    {
    //For First Loop It Should Be UserName
    echo $row['userName']; 

   //For 2nd Loop It Should Be pageUserName
    echo $row['pageUserName']; 

    } ?>
```

This is the code but the echo gets print together i want separate echo for userName and another for pageUserName one after another and not together

Comment: Why all the PHP Stop/Start/Stop/Start..... that is all PHP so start by removing all but the first `<?php` and the last `?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN page ON user.userID=page.userID");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['userName'] . " " . $row['pageUserName'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

**NOTE**

You should not use open / end php tag in each row.

You can concatenate your string with `.` character as in my example.

**WARNING**

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or PDO instead.

**UPDATE**

Based on OP edit in his original question, I think I get it what he wants. When you iterate through your results, instead `echo` put them into 2 arrays.

Then iterate through both of them. I write for this a little function called `showNames`, so you avoid code repetation.

```
function showNames($array) {
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        echo $item."<br>";
    }
}

//Init arrays
$userNames = [];
$pageUserNames = [];

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
    //Put values into the 2 arrays
    $userNames[] = $row['userName'];
    $pageUserNames[] = $row['pageUserName'];
}

//Show the items of arrays
showNames($userNames);
echo '<hr>';
showNames($pageUserNames);
```

Comment: Downvoter please explain why did you downvote all the answers?

Comment: We sure did, maybe the english explanation is not the best. But given that there are 4 answers that point to the same solution, it might not be our fault...

Comment: i don't want to concatenate  those two names but i want those two names separately and not in same echo results one result for username and another result for pageUserName for understanding take example of fb news feed they have different results for user and pages in same query so i want that

Comment: Sorry, I am not on facebook. What is the desired result? I dont get it. `one after another` What does it mean? In a new row, or separated by a sapce? Like `Fistname Lastname`? Show me an example here. Anyway, did you tried my code?

Comment: check that image which has separate results for users and pages but in same query i want single query for that kind of result

Comment: Thats not errors, I think you mean the array creation. Older PHP can not parse it, change it to `$userNames = array();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN page ON user.userID=page.userID") ;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc());
{
    echo $row['userName']." ".$row['pageUserName']."<br />";
} 
?>
```

Comment: i don't want to concatenate those two names but i want those two names separately one after another  and not in same echo results one result for username and another result for pageUserName for understanding take example of fb news feed they have different results for user and pages in same query so i want that

Answer (score 0):

inside loop make a single line as follows:

```
<?php echo $row['userName']. " - ". $row['pageUserName']."<br>" ?>
```

Comment: i don't want to concatenate those two names but i want those two names separately one after another and not in same echo results one result for username and another result for pageUserName for understanding take example of fb news feed they have different results for user and pages in same query so i want that

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
<?php  
  $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN page ON user.userID=page.userID") ;
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc())
  {
    echo $row['userName'] . ' ' . $row['pageUserName'];
  }
?>
```

Comment: what will be the output for this ? will it be like fb news feed whic displays both users as well as pages in same query ?

Comment: Downvoter, if you think the answer is not correct, you could at least point us to what you believe the answer is about.

@AbhiBurk This will show "Username - PageUsername" for each row in the query

Comment: And as this is basically a _Try This_ answer - Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN page ON user.userID=page.userID"

You say that this query doesn't return the columns from the page table? Are you sure?...

Comment: The query DOES indeed get all columns from both tables. The OP asks for "echo this two Names in same while loop one after another". I agree that he probably should not be coding, given the code written, but hey, we tried to help him. But let the OP answer if we solved it or not

Comment: Oooppppssssssssss. Edited so I could remove the DV

Comment: In that case this question is so unclear as to what OP  actually wants from us I give up

Comment: Answer was not finished, requirements were bad and I was trying to get some more info out of it. I know it could be a comment, but common, given his english I thought this would be far easier. Obviusly I would have added the mysql_ problem, and I don't want to spend more time on this, but downvoting all answers just because you think it's not what you would answer ain't right.

Comment: Yes, let's leave it here. Sorry about this discussion

Comment: Thats not why I did it, I believed the query would not return data from the page table that was why I dv's

Comment: Ok, no problem, remove downvotes from other answers and that's it. Cheers

Comment: Dont apologise, I was wrong. Put me right anytime I am wrong by all means

Comment: For First Loop i want echo to be username and for 2nd pageUserName i dont want to concat this two field at same time with same result